# What is the best way to use subqueries with SQLiteCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, database-connection

The code I have now is the following:

```
using (dbConnection)
{
    if (dbConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) dbConnection.Open();

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM BoardStates WHERE Move = @subquery", dbConnection);
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT MAX(Move) FROM BoardStates", dbConnection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subquery", cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Game: " + reader["Game"] + "\tMove: " + reader["Move"] + "\tState: " + reader["State"]);
    }
}
```

I want to return the row of the last move that is made. I do this by using 2 seperate SQLiteCommands. Is there a way to optimize this or by combining it into 1 SQLiteCommand?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq) says:

> A SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as a scalar quantity. A SELECT used as a scalar quantity must return a result set with a single column. The result of the expression is the value of the only column in the first row returned by the SELECT statement.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM BoardStates
WHERE Move = (SELECT MAX(Move)
              FROM BoardStates);
```

But to get the row with the largest value, you can simply use sorting:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM BoardStates
ORDER BY Move DESC
LIMIT 1;
```